# C# How to find number of occurence of the lowest number in an array with random numbers?

Tags: c#

I am trying to show the number of occurrences of the lowest number in an array with randomly generated numbers. The lowest number is determined at the end of the array(in my program)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Assignment2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] n = new int[20]; // make new array of 20 elements
            int i;
            int min = 151;
            int count = 0;
            Random random = new Random();

            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                n[i] = random.Next(0, 150); // give n[i] 20 random numbers //

                if (n[i] < min) // Find the lowest number in random generated array
                {
                    min = n[i];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Element {0} = {1}", i, n[i]); // show the elements and it's values

                if (n[i] == min) // number of occurence perhaps?
                {
                    count++;
                }
                
                if (i == 19) // Print smallest number/number of occurence
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Smallest number = {0}", min);
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of occurence = {0}", count);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: From what I can gather, the count is wrong due to the fact that you're incrementing lower numbers without resetting the count.

Comment: Did you attach a debugger and step through your code line by line?

Comment: surely you should have a loop that loads the array, and then a loop that inspects the array. ou  cannot count the number of min values otherwise.

Comment: @pm100 That's not true, the code above works fine if he resets `count = 1` when a new `min` is found and the two `if` blocks are combined into an `if/else if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question isn't clear, the reason that the count is incorrect is that the `count` variable doesn't reset if it finds a new lower number. To fix, simply add `count = 0;` when setting the new `min` variable, like:

```
if (n[i] < min) // Find the lowest number in random generated array
{
    min = n[i];
    count = 0; // reset count
}
```